# should I use PrintWriter to wrap BufferedWriter?

Tags: java

in the api,java said that,'Unless prompt output is required, it is advisable to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write() operations may be costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters'.I tried the comparation many times,it turns out that,it costs less time if I do not use PrintWriter to wrap BufferedWriter.
so does it mean that,I do not have to wrap on the 'console'?
there is my simple code that compare the two.

```
public static void PrintWrite(String path, String content) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path)));
    pw.write(content);
    pw.close();
}
public static void BufferedWrite(String path, String content) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
    bw.write(content);
    bw.close();
}   
private static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String s = "";
    String path = "D:\\out.txt";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        s += "kjuatlistened";
    }
    try
    {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        //PrintWrite(path,s);
        BufferedWrite(path,s);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        Printer.println("done,elapse " + (end - start) + " s");
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, from what I have read and gathered if you need more functionality then wrap the class. If it works without wrapping the class and you have no need for other methods that the wrapper class would give you then do not wrap the class. I have read many mix ideas of this but from what I gathered wrapping a class is only done (for the most part) if you need more functionality which the wrapper class provides.

Comment: no,doug hauf,I just ocnsider why the jdk said that it is better to wrap,from my part,maybe it relevant to something unsafe.and because from my test,'wrap' using more time...so...i posted the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're certainly adding a layer of processing when you wrap one object in another.

The main reason for using PrintWriter is the wealth of convenience functions which do intelligent output of various things. If you don't need that capability, you wouldn't use a PrintWriter at all.

The point of a BufferedWriter is to allow output to be buffered and then written in a batch.  I/O to file systems, the Internet, etc. is costly, and a large fraction of that cost is in generating the connection in the first place, and then waiting while each I/O operation completes.  If you batch I/O to and from external devices, you can really reduce the overall cost because output (or input) can be batched--and you end up waiting for completion just once per batch, rather than once per I/O operation.  For an "interesting" test, try writing characters to your FileWriter one at a time, then do the same thing with a BufferedWriter wrapping your FileWriter.  I think in the latter case you'll see a large improvement.

Comment: got it,I saw that 'PrintWriter' has much more method than 'BufferedWriter',does it what you mean?and Thanks very much your response...

Comment: Yes--all those extra methods are there to make it easy to write various things to the stream.  With most writers, you have to generate the right byte sequence yourself.  PrintWriter makes a lot of that easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your underlying question, but...

Wrapping a BufferedWriter with a PrintWriter pretty much has to to be slower, since it is added a layer of calls.

System.out and .err are PrintStream objects, not PrintWriter. Is that what you mean by the console? I'm pretty sure you should not wrap either of them.

Comment: I confused about this because why the api said that,it is recommend to wrap BufferedWriter using PrintWriter,which,however,from my test,it turns out that 'warp' operation did cost much more time,so that is where I was confused.Sorry...I shouldn't involed with 'console'.

Comment: In addition,I just confused about why it said 'Unless prompt output is required',and what situation?

Comment: If you need the output to appear on the final output stream exactly when you write it, don't use a BufferedWriter.  The BufferedWriter can hold the output as long as it likes in its buffer before flushing said output to the final destination.  So in this context, "prompt output" means "output which appears at the final destination as quickly as possible" instead of "output which appears at the final destination whenever the buffered writer feels like writing it out."